# stata odbc sqlfile

Tags: sql, odbc, stata

I am trying to load data from database (either MS Access or SQL server) using `odbc sqlfile` it seems that the code is running with any error but I am not getting data. I am using the following code `odbc sqlfile("sqlcode.sql"),dsn("mysqlodbcdata")`. Note that `sqlcode.sql` contains just `sql` statement with `SELECT`. The thing is that the same `sql` code is giving data with `odbc load,exec(sqlstmt) dsn("mysqlodbcdata")`. Can anyone suggest how can I use `odbc sqlfile` to import data? This would be a great help for me.

Thanks
Joy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sqlfile doesn't load any data. It just executes (and displays the results when the loud option is specified), without loading any data into Stata. That's somewhat counter-intuitive, but true. The reasons are somewhat opaquely explained in the pdf/dead tree manual entry for the odbc command.

Here's a more helpful answer. Suppose you have your SQL file named sqlcode.sql. You can open it in Stata (as long as it's not *too* long, where *too long* depends on your flavor of Stata). Basically, -file read- reads the SQL code line by line, storing the results in a local macro named exec. Then you pass that macro as an argument to the -odbc load- command:

**Updated Code To Deal With Some Double Quotes Issues**

Cut & paste the following code into a file called loadsql.ado, which you should put in directory where Stata can see it (like ~/ado/personal). You can find such directories with the -adopath- command.

```
program define loadsql
*! Load the output of an SQL file into Stata, version 1.3 (dvmaster@gmail.com)
version 14.1
syntax using/, DSN(string) [User(string) Password(string) CLEAR NOQuote LOWercase SQLshow ALLSTRing DATESTRing]

#delimit;
tempname mysqlfile exec line;

file open `mysqlfile' using `"`using'"', read text;
file read `mysqlfile' `line';

while r(eof)==0 {;
    local `exec' `"``exec'' ``line''"';
    file read `mysqlfile' `line';
};

file close `mysqlfile';


odbc load, exec(`"``exec''"') dsn(`"`dsn'"') user(`"`user'"') password(`"`password'"') `clear' `noquote' `lowercase' `sqlshow' `allstring' `datestring';

end;
```

/* All done! */

The syntax in Stata is

```
loadsql using "./sqlfile.sql", dsn("mysqlodbcdata")
```

You can also add all the other odbc load options, such as clear, as well. Obviously, you will need to change the file path and the odbc parameters to reflect your setup. This code should do the same thing as -odbc sqlfile("sqlfile.sql"), dsn("mysqlodbcdata")- plus actually load the data.

I also added the functionality to specify your DB credentials like this:

```
loadsql using "./sqlfile.sql", dsn("mysqlodbcdata") user("user_name") password("not12345")
```

Comment: This might get confused by comments in your SQL file.

Comment: Hi @dimitriy, I've tried the code and receive an error for a very simple "select count(*) ..." statement. It reads "table or exec() is required". Any advice? It would also be nice to run a simple sql statement interactively in stata. It doesn't seem likely, but perhaps my use of quotations around sql variables is messing things up?

Comment: Quotes do appear to mess it up. Can you give me an example of how you are using quotes in your sql file? I might be able to hack something.

Comment: One example of the code is:

select count(*) from "My Table"."Good Variable";

A lot of my tables have names with spaces or capitalization that require quotations to write.

Comment: I think I fixed that bug and turned the code into an file. Let me know if that fixes the problem or you have any other issues.

Comment: Currently, "--XYZ"-style comments will break this. /*XYZ*/-style comments should work fine.

Comment: I've added some Ruby kludge to this script, which gets around the issue with comments beginning with --. https://gist.github.com/masnick/513b1f5fc1cb2e80c4bac2ca79a8c177

Answer (score 1):

For "--XYZ" style comments, do something like this (assuming you don't have "--" in your SQL code):

```
if strpos(`"``line''"', "--") > 0 {;
    local `line' = substr(`"``line''"', 1, strpos(`"``line''"', "--")-1);
    };
```

I had to post this as an answer otherwise the formatting would've been all messed up, but it's obviously referring to Dimitriy's code.
(You could also define a local macro holding the position of the "--" string to make your code a little cleaner.)