# Running SQL in Stata

Tags: sql, stata

I am trying to load data from SQL server management studio into Stata. How do I get Stata to run the .sql file? I have used the -ado- procedure from another post, but it does not work because my database has a username and password.

Original -ado- code:

```
program define loadsql
*! Load the output of an SQL file into Stata, version 1.2 (dvmaster@gmail.com)
version 12.1
syntax using/, DSN(string) [CLEAR NOQuote LOWercase SQLshow ALLSTRing DATESTRing]

#delimit;
tempname mysqlfile exec line;

file open `mysqlfile' using `"`using'"', read text;
file read `mysqlfile' `line';

while r(eof)==0 {;
    local `exec' `"``exec'' ``line''"';
    file read `mysqlfile' `line';
};

file close `mysqlfile';


odbc load, exec(`"``exec''"') dsn(`"`dsn'"') `clear' `noquote' `lowercase' `sqlshow' `allstring' `datestring';

end;
```

Comment: You may be able to store your password as part of the ODBC settings for that DSN.

Comment: Thank you for your original posting! Unfortunately Stata requires that I re-enter the user name and password even though I have it stored in the ODBC settings for that DSN,

Comment: That's very bit weird. In any case, I edited the original code to give you this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`help odbc` discusses connect_options for connecting to odbc data sources. Two of which are `u(userId)` and `p(password)` which can be added to the original code written by @Dimitriy V. Masterov (see post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270275/stata-odbc-sqlfile)).

I believe you should be able to connect using SQL Server authentication  by adding the `u(string)` and `p(string)` as additional options following `syntax` in the ado file, and then again down below following

```
 odbc load, exec(`"``exec''"') dsn(`"`dsn'"')
```

This would also require that you pass these arguments to the program when you call it:

```
loadsql using "./sqlfile.sql", dsn("mysqlodbcdata") u(userId) p(Password)
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that would work as well, but when I call it                       loadsql using "./sqlfile.sql", dsn("mysqlodbcdata") u(userId) p(Password)        stata returns 'option u() not allowed'                                                                       I think the error might be in this line:                                                 odbc load, exec(`"``exec''"') dsn(`"`dsn'"') u(`"`u'"') p(`"`p'"') `clear' `noquote' `lowercase' `sqlshow' `allstring' `datestring';                                     because user and password are not in quotes when I call it

Comment: did you add `User(string)` and `Password(string)` to the bracketed section following `syntax`?

Comment: @ander2ed is correct. I edited the code linked in this answer to add this option.

Comment: yes, i did add it add that section, but i did not put it inside the brackets. Thank you both for your help.